# react native use navigation prop in fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I am pretty new to react native. I am using react navigation in my react-native app. I am passing some props from one screen to another, and I need to use one of the props in a fetch I am trying to execute within the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. With everything I have tried, it sends the value for the "type" key, but it sends nothing for the "location" key (see code below). Could someone help me with what am I missing or doing wrong? I have tried several things to pass the prop but nothing has worked yet.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    var data = {
      type: 'r',
      location: params.location
    }
    return fetch('http://myapisite', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }
      )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson,
        }, function() {
          // do something with new state
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: How is this component navigated into? How are you setting the location param?

Comment: First check whether params.location is undefined or it has value?

Comment: while navigating, send the location param. `this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName', { location: 'some location' });`

Comment: @Kraylog it is navigated to from a different class/screen in the same file and the location param is sent via navigate. If i set the same `const` for params in the “render” section it returns the data just fine, just not within the “componentDidMount” section. @HemadriDasari it sends null to the fetch api so I assume undefined. @vijayst that is exactly what I am sending.

Comment: I'd check whether react navigation is mounting the component without the param and then updates - try using `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps` to see if that's the case.

Comment: @Kraylog ok thanks. So I’m not crazy though, what I have should theoretically work?

Comment: Yeah, it looks right.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. I am not 100% certain why what I had didn't work, but when I changed it to the following, it worked as expected:

```
const {state} = this.props.navigation;
var data = {
  type: 'restaurant',
  location: state.params.location
}
return fetch('http://mylink', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
  )
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      dataSource: responseJson,
    }, function() {
      // do something with new state
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```